# React SDK Contact Registration

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk, react

Using the [React SDK](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk) for MC Push is there a way to [Delay Registration](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html) using the iOS SDK?

There is a method to update Contact Key, but it's unclear how this works. If the Contact is registered already (using the random GUID), will this update that contact or create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to initialize the Marketing Cloud SDK with [delayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html#delay-registration-until-contact-key-is-set) for both Android (ref. [Android Init](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/java/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/react/MainApplication.java#L50)) and iOS (ref. [iOS Init](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk/blob/master/example/ios/example/AppDelegate.m#L41))